# Modifying Rows & columns of a dataset

Tags: python, excel, jupyter-notebook, data-science, data-manipulation

I have the data like this

```
category | Sub-category | Variable | 1990 | 1991 | 1992
C1        sc1               v1         1      2      3
                            v2         4      5      6
                            v3         7      8      9
          sc2               v1         10     11     12
                            v2         13     14     15
                            v3         16     17     18
```

I want to convert it into this

```
    category | Sub-category | Variable | year | vals
       C1        sc1            v1       1990    1
                                         1991    2
                                         1992    3
                                V2       1990    4
                                         1991    5
                                         1992    6
                                V3       1990    7
                                         1991    8
                                        `1992`   9
and so on
```

How do I do this in python [&/or excel]?

Comment: In Excel Power Query you can do this by unpivoting the "year" columns and then re-pivoting on the Values column. You'll need to do some extra steps to handle the empty cells in your Source and Results tables, but other than that, it's pretty straightforward.  Please edit your question to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python you can use `melt` function (from pandas library).

`Pandas.melt()` unpivots a DataFrame from wide format to long format.

`melt()` function is useful to massage a DataFrame into a format where one or more columns are identifier variables, while all other columns, considered measured variables, are unpivoted to the row axis, leaving just two non-identifier columns, variable and value.

***Usage:***

```
pd.melt(x, id_vars=['category', 'Sub-category','Variable'], var_name='year', value_name='vals')
```